# flask-mysql ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to make a simple program using flask + mysql.
I just receive two arguments in a POST and write to the database:

```
@app.route('/upd',methods=['POST'])
def upd():
   _lat = request.form['lat']
   _lng = request.form['lng']

   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.execute('insert into locations(lat,lng) values (?,?)',(_lat,_lng,))
   cur.commit()

   return jsonify(request.form)
```

The problem is that when i try to post the data from  the client , i am getting:

```
ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2018 23:46:14] "POST /upd HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

If i comment the SQL statement, the client will receive the output of jsonify which looks correct:

```
{
"lat": "3.2001",
"lng": "-11.45465"
}
```

Comment: MySQL uses printf style placeholders for queries, so you need to replace ? ? with %s %s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style, [according to the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html):

> The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style).

`cur.execute('insert into locations(lat,lng) values (%s,%s)' % (_lat,_lng,))`

should work.